# Почему Яндекс.Переводчик переводит слово "Moscow" как "Хаят Москва"?

Tags: яндекс-переводчик

Подключил Яндекс.переводчик API, слово Moscow не переводится, оставляет как есть. А на сайте дает два варианта: один — "хаят Москва", другой — "Подмосковье". Гугл нормально переводит. Весь мир знает, что означает Moscow, а Яндекс — нет. Как быть-то, объясните, пожалуйста?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разобрался, сервер каждый день по несколько тыс. получает список адресов на латинице и на англ.(смешанный), задача было создать транслит на русский. На Яндекс отправлял по 10кб, разделив каждый адрес "@@", и Яндекс, видимо, понимал это как емайл, что ли, потом заменил на "::" - теперь переводит. Всё ок. Беру обратно свои слова. Но на счет хаят москва я не придумал. )

Answer (score 1):

Предположу, что вы что-то не так делаете. [Яндекс.Перевод](http://translate.yandex.ru/?text=Moscow&lang=en-ru) в основном ("нулевом") значении дает Москва, под 1 дает перевод опять же Москва, но с примером "Hyatt Moscow – Хаятт Москва", под 2 - Подмосковье. Не удивлюсь, если в третьем значении у вас получится "Московский Патриархат".

Я не спец в Яндекс API, но уверен, что код помог бы понять, в чем проблема.